# Events QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent работают, только если graphicsview активно qt

Tags: c++, qt

Как сделать так, чтобы при запуске программы сразу graphicsview становился активным и события срабатывали. А то необходимо сначала кликнуть на сцену.

Comment: Какие события? Можно пример кода

Comment: киньте фокус на график вью. `my_graphics_view->setFocus(...);`

Comment: Спасибо. Кинул фокус и все теперь события обрабатываются как надо!